# How to convert JWK public key to PEM format in C++

Tags: c++, openssl, public-key, pem, jwk

[Here](https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp) is an online tool that converts JWK to PEM and vice-versa.

I want the same in C++ code.

For JWK:

```
{  
  "kty":"RSA",
  "e":"AQAB",
  "kid":"18b4f6a6-f9ec-456b-a3e8-04af5e97790e",
  "n":"tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb-h0qup5jznOvOr-Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIvkvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr_EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiMy3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU_BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZmWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw-7V-P7jwrQRFfQVXw"
}
```

The online tool gives PEM:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtVKUtcx/n9rt5afY/2WF
NvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb+h0qup5j
znOvOr+Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIv
kvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr/EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiM
y3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU/BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZ
mWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw+7V+P7jwrQRFfQV
XwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And vice-versa. So the `kty` and `kid` fields are also somehow included in the PEM.

I've tried OpenSSL like this:

```
 std::string_view nnInBase64Url = "tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb-h0qup5jznOvOr-Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIvkvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr_EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiMy3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU_BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZmWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw-7V-P7jwrQRFfQVXw";
  std::string_view eeInBase64Url = "AQAB";
  auto nnBin = cppcodec::base64_url_unpadded::decode(nnInBase64Url);
  auto eeBin = cppcodec::base64_url_unpadded::decode(eeInBase64Url);
  BIGNUM* modul = BN_bin2bn(nnBin.data(),nnBin.size(),NULL);
  BIGNUM* expon = BN_bin2bn(eeBin.data(),eeBin.size(),NULL);
  RSA* rr = RSA_new();
  RSA_set0_key(rr, modul, expon, NULL);
  BIO* ff = BIO_new_file("public.pem","w+");
  PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(ff, rr);
```

But it gave me a different PEM, that should be obvious, as at least, I didn't specify the `kid`.

Finally, the questions is: how can I implement the proper conversion using OpenSSL or another C++ lib, so it will also take into consideration the `kid` and `kty` fields and result with the same PEM as the online tool gives?

Comment: Related discussion that may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264157/how-to-convert-a-public-key-from-a-jwk-into-pem-for-openssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found using [CryptoPP](https://www.cryptopp.com/) and [CryptoPP-PEM](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-pem):

```
std::string getRSAPublicKeyInPEMFormat(std::string_view nnInBase64UrlUnpadded, std::string_view eeInBase64UrlUnpadded)
{
  auto nnBin = cppcodec::base64_url_unpadded::decode(nnInBase64UrlUnpadded);
  auto eeBin = cppcodec::base64_url_unpadded::decode(eeInBase64UrlUnpadded);
  CryptoPP::Integer nn(nnBin.data(), nnBin.size(), CryptoPP::Integer::UNSIGNED, CryptoPP::BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
  CryptoPP::Integer ee(eeBin.data(), eeBin.size(), CryptoPP::Integer::UNSIGNED, CryptoPP::BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
  CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
  pubKey.Initialize(nn, ee);
  std::ostringstream pem;
  CryptoPP::FileSink sink(pem);
  CryptoPP::PEM_Save(sink, pubKey);
  return pem.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were very close to the solution in your first implementation already, only at the last step, instead of `PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey` you should have used `PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY`.

```
  std::string_view nnInBase64Url = "tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb-h0qup5jznOvOr-Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIvkvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr_EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiMy3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU_BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZmWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw-7V-P7jwrQRFfQVXw";
  std::string_view eeInBase64Url = "AQAB";
  auto nnBin = cppcodec::base64_url_unpadded::decode(nnInBase64Url);
  auto eeBin = cppcodec::base64_url_unpadded::decode(eeInBase64Url);
  BIGNUM* modul = BN_bin2bn(nnBin.data(),nnBin.size(),NULL);
  BIGNUM* expon = BN_bin2bn(eeBin.data(),eeBin.size(),NULL);
  RSA* rr = RSA_new();
  RSA_set0_key(rr, modul, expon, NULL);
  BIO* ff = BIO_new_file("public.pem","w+");
  PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(ff, rr);
```

For more information, please refer to the quotes from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818567/openssl-difference-between-pem-write-rsapublickey-and-pem-write-rsa-pubkey)

> The RSAPublicKey functions process an RSA public key using an RSA structure. The public key is encoded using a PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey structure.
>
> The RSA_PUBKEY functions also process an RSA public key using an RSA structure. However the public key is encoded using a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure and an error occurs if the public key is not RSA .

and from [RFC 3280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3280/?include_text=1),

> 4.1.2.7  Subject Public Key Info
>
> This field is used to carry the public key and identify the algorithm
>     with which the key is used (e.g., RSA, DSA, or Diffie-Hellman).  The
>     algorithm is identified using the AlgorithmIdentifier structure
>     specified in section 4.1.1.2.  The object identifiers for the
>     supported algorithms and the methods for encoding the public key
>     materials (public key and parameters) are specified in [PKIXALGS].